# How is a useless statement affecting this C program?

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote following C program to find the largest number of a given array using recursion. This program is giving correct output. But there is a line of code (int x=1;)
which has no role in the program, yet if I remove it, this program starts gives wrong output. I am not able to understand why? Please explain

```
   #include<stdio.h>

  int largestElement(int ar[], int length,int i,int lar)
  {
      int largest, j;
      j=i;
      largest=lar;

    if(j<length)
    {


        if(ar[j]>ar[j+1])
        {

        ar[j+1]=ar[j];
        }

        largest=ar[j+1];
        largestElement(ar,length,i+1,largest);

        return largest;
    }

   printf("\nlargest number of array = %d ",largest);

    }

   int main()
  {
   int a[10]={2,22,87,1,9,99,11,90,1,0};// Given an array of 10 elements
   int x=1; //If I remove this statement the output is some random number
            //but if I keep this line I get correct output, despite the fact 
            // that x is of no use in this program.
   largestElement(a,10,0,0);
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: When `j=9` what is `ar[j+1]`? (hint: *undefined behavior*)

Comment: Looks like you're overstepping the array when you try to access `ar[j+1]`, and your compiler is putting the `x` value immediately after `a`'s last element where it acts like a sentinel.

Comment: Why are you waning to use recursion? There is a trivial procedural solution to the problem without creating multiple function stacks.

Answer (score 1):

As identified above, the problem with your `largestElement` function is you invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your conditional `if(ar[j]>ar[j+1])` and then again in your assignment `ar[j+1]=ar[j];` when `j = 9` because you are attempting to access memory beyond the end of your array. This invoked *Undefined Behavior* in  your code, which could then lead it to provide the wanted results or `SEGFAULT` or anything in between.

The fact that it behaves correctly when you declare an additional integer int `x=1;` following your array, is just a side effect of the implementation defined behavior where the additional integer `x` immediately follows the array providing at least on additional defined bit of integer storage that saves you from an immediate SEGFAULT. Since you are assigning the largest value by swapping elements as you go, it is likely your largest value ends up in `x` which is why removing it changes your output.  **But none of this is defined behavior** so there is no guarantee.

If you wanted to recursively find the largest number, then do not swap elements at all, simply return the largest. Something simple like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN */

int largestElement (int *ar, int length, int idx, int largest)
{
    if (idx == length)      /* recursion exit condition */
        return largest;

    if (ar[idx] > largest)  /* largest test */
        largest = ar[idx];

    /* recursive call */
    return largestElement (ar, length, idx + 1, largest);
}

int main (void) {

    int a[10] = {2, 22, 87, 1, 9, 99, 11, 90, 1, 0},
    largest = largestElement (a, 10, 0, INT_MIN);

    printf("\nlargest number of array = %d\n", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrlargestrecurse

largest number of array = 99
```

**Note:** there is no need to use a recursive approach to begin with, and use of recursion is discouraged where a procedural solution is readily available. Why? Every recursive call is a separate function call, and the system must create a complete function stack for each recursive call. Now for a 10 element array, it is immaterial, but it adds up quickly for million element arrays or more. A simple procedural implementation would look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int largestElement (int *ar, int length)
{
    int largest = INT_MIN;

    while (length--)
        if (ar[length] > largest)
            largest = ar[length];

    return largest;
}

int main()
{
    int a[10] = {2, 22, 87, 1, 9, 99, 11, 90, 1, 0},
    largest = largestElement (a, 10);

    printf("\nlargest number of array = %d\n", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Great program , but can you tell me why you have used INT_MIN in this program, I tried to see its value by  printf("%d ",INT_MIN); I got some random value -21473637388.

Comment: Sure, when you are looking for a maximum number. you always start with the lowest number in the range. Otherwise, you would get an incorrect answer if your values were all, e.g. `-1,891,255, -21,976,282, -1,956,385`. In other words if all your numbers you need to find the max of are less than what you initialize max to (e.g. `max = 0;`, your answer will remain `0` and never reflect the true max of  `-1,891,255,`. Same works for minimums. If you are looking for the smallest integer, initialize `int min = INT_MAX;`